# Ext JS 6.2, How to convert date to sql format:2017-08-25 16:34?

Tags: javascript, datetime, extjs, datepicker, sencha-touch

I'm using Ext Js v6.2 Grid, In my application, I've Datetimefield, For user I showing the date format as

```
format: 'd/m/Y H:i'
```

but On submitting data to sql, I need to convert as sql format,

```
format: 2017-08-25 16:34
```

Here's my code, I'm getting output as `2016-03-14T18:30:00.000Z` But I need it as `format: 2017-08-25 16:34`.

Please correct my code if I'm wrong, I've searched in documentation and other stuff it doesn't help.

```
var headerObj = page.getForm().getFieldValues();
var hdrData = "<HeaderData>" + x2js.json2xml_str(headerObj)" +</HeaderData>";
console.log(hdrData);
```

```js
{
  xtype: 'datefield',
  border: true,
  width: '100%',
  fieldLabel: 'somefield',
  name: 'somefield',
  format: 'd/m/Y H:i',
  submitFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i',
}
```

Comment: This is only the component definition. Show your submit code.

Comment: @Alexander updated my code, I'm getting fieldvalue as json and converting them to xml, so that i can pass xml to sql.

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS doesn't give a function to do that. You have to make a custom function that convert your date:

```
Date.prototype.toNormalizedDate = function(){
    var normalizedDate = new Date(Date.UTC(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), this.getDate(), this.getHours(), this.getMinutes(), this.getSeconds()));
    return normalizedDate.toISOString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getFieldValues` method returns the model data. Model data is intended for use with a store model, which can usually work with javascript date, therefore, that function returns a javascript date from datefields. Only during the serialization, the javascript date is then converted to a string, using the browser default (because the serialization function already expects the input to be strings only).

What you may perhaps want to try is `form.getSubmitData`. This function will return string values for all fields; in the case of the date field, the date is then formatted using `submitFormat`.

The second possibility is to use a model for submission, not the form.

Define a model with a proxy for load/save operation:

```
Ext.define('MyModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields:[{
        name: 'somefield',
        type: 'date',
        dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i'
    }],
    proxy: {
        url: '...'
    }
})
```

then either create new record and put into form:

```
form.loadRecord(Ext.create('MyModel'))
```

or edit existing record from server:

```
MyModel.load(id, {
    success: function(record) {
        form.loadRecord(record);
    }
})
```

And then save it to the server again:

```
form.updateRecord();
form.getRecord().save({
    success: function() {
        Ext.alert('Saved!');
    }
});
```

This has the neat side-effect that you can add the original XML reader and writer of ExtJS to your model proxy, and you can do away with your own XML conversion function.

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJs docs form have method to get all values of form using **getValues**. You can refer [ExtJs docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html#method-getValues)

I have create small demo to show you, how it is working.

[Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26oj)

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'Date',
    margin: 10,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'datefield',
        anchor: '100%',
        fieldLabel: 'From',
        format: 'd/m/Y H:i',
        submitFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i',
        allowBlank: false,
        name: 'date'
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Submit Date',
        formBind: true,
        handler: function () {
            var date = this.up('form').getValues().date;
            /* this is also one way to get value by date field.
                date =this.up('form').down('datefield').getValue(),
                submittedDate = Ext.Date.format(date,'Y-m-d H:i');
            */
            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', `Selected date is <b>${date}</b>`);
        }
    }]
});
```